# AngularJS ng-class don't change when the conditions are changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing a `wizard-form` using `ui-router`, following this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router).

Currently I'm trying to do like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="status-buttons-wizard" class="text-center">
   <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".item"> <span></span>Item</a>
   <a ng-class="{ disabled: !ItemCheckPass, enabled: ItemCheckPass}" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".location"><span></span>Location</a>
   <a ng-show="!IsAuthenticated" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".account"><span></span>Account</a>
   <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".social"><span></span>Social</a>
</div>

.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: .5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.enabled {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

**Check fired:**

```
<a ui-sref="post_add.location" class="btn btn-orange" ng-class="{disabled: addItem_form.$invalid}" ng-click="itemCheck()">Continue <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></a>
```

**JS:**

```
//data checks
$scope.ItemCheckPass = false;
$scope.itemCheck= function(){
    if(typeof $scope.AddItem === 'undefined' || $scope.AddItem == null){return false;}
    if(typeof $scope.AddItem.title === 'undefined' || $scope.AddItem.title == null){return false;}
    if(typeof $scope.AddItem.descr === 'undefined' || $scope.AddItem.descr == null){return false;}
    if(typeof $scope.AddItem.category === 'undefined' || $scope.AddItem.category == null){return false;}
    if(typeof $scope.AddItem.subcategory === 'undefined' || $scope.AddItem.subcategory == null){return false;}
    if(typeof $scope.AddItem.email === 'undefined' || $scope.AddItem.email == null){return false;}
    if(typeof $scope.AddItem.price === 'undefined' || $scope.AddItem.price == null){return false;}
    $scope.ItemCheckPass = true;
    return true;
}
```

Everything works well. As you can see, I'm trying to change the class of the tag `<a>`, based on a condition, and for unknown reason, the `ng-class` isn't changing the class when the `$scope.ItemCheckPass (boolean)` changes.

What can be a problem?

OR

What is the better way to disable the steps changing for user?

Comment: please show the code where you have implemented the condition

Comment: when and how ItemCheckPass initialise?

Comment: updated. `$scope.itemCheck` is fired on the "continue" anchor

Comment: ng-class="{'disabled': !ItemCheckPass}", i think you forgot single-quotation in your ngClass

Comment: exactly u  missed the quotation in your class

Comment: update to: ng-class=" ItemCheckPass ? 'disabled':'enabled'  " ... it's better

Comment: Seems to work OK as is ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/TWVU7fExrNJbbNJ2UtQF?p=preview. Can you replicate the problem in a Plunker?

Comment: @user1935987, are you sure $scope.itemCheck function worked for you? i mean you object "$scope.AddItem" finally return true?

Comment: seems like quotes doesn't change anything. Also without them, the `disabled` class working anyway

Comment: $scope.itemCheck function is worked  and return `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that with each state initialization, the variables on controller are renewed.

The solutions is to make routing like this:

```
    .state('post_add', {
        url: '/post_add',
        templateUrl: '/view/post_wizard/form.html',
        controller: 'postWizardMainController',
        abstract:true
    })
    .state('post_add.item', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: '/view/post_wizard/form-item.html',
        controller: 'postWizardController'
    })
    .state('post_add.location', {
        url: '/location',
        templateUrl: '/view/post_wizard/form-location.html',
        controller: 'postWizardController'
    })
    .state('post_add.account', {
        url: '/account',
        templateUrl: '/view/post_wizard/form-account.html',
        controller: 'postWizardController'
    })
    .state('post_add.social', {
        url: '/social',
        templateUrl: '/view/post_wizard/form-social.html',
        controller: 'postWizardController'
    })
    .state('post_add.success', {
        url: '/success',
        templateUrl: '/view/post_wizard/form-success.html',
    });
```

and put the check variables and methods in `postWizardMainController`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your class declarations are not inside of `<style>` tags. I tried it on my machine and it worked fine.

So you'll change:

```
.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: .5;
    pointer-events: none;
 }
.enabled {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

to this:

```
<style>
    .disabled {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        opacity: .5;
        pointer-events: none;
     }
    .enabled {
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: all;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi. no. Sorry, i forget to leave an answer which i found